# Is there a python grub.cfg parser?

Tags: python, parsing, grub

Does anyone know of a python parser for grub2's grub.cfg file?

I'm trying to get the "menuentry" by device partition (root), e.g.

```
hd0,msdos1: ['Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-15-generic',
            'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-15-generic (recovery mode)',
            'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-14-generic']
hd2,msdos1: ["Windows 7 (on /dev/sdc1)"]
```

etc.

Solution:

```
re.findall("menuentry ['\"](.*?)['\"].*?set root='(.*?)'", x, re.S)
```

> [('Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-15-generic', '(hd0,msdos1)'), ('Ubuntu,
>   with Linux 3.0.0-15-generic (recovery mode)', '(hd0,msdos1)'),
>   ('Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-14-generic', '(hd0,msdos1)'), ('Ubuntu,
>   with Linux 3.0.0-14-generic (recovery mode)', '(hd0,msdos1)'),
>   ('Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-13-generic', '(hd0,msdos1)'), ('Ubuntu,
>   with Linux 3.0.0-13-generic (recovery mode)', '(hd0,msdos1)'),
>   ('Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic', '(hd0,msdos1)'), ('Ubuntu,
>   with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (recovery mode)', '(hd0,msdos1)'),
>   ('Memory test (memtest86+)', '(hd0,msdos1)'), ('Memory test
>   (memtest86+, serial console 115200)', '(hd0,msdos1)'), ('Windows 7
>   (on /dev/sdc1)', '(hd2,msdos1)')]

Comment: Oh, you people want everything done for you... Just make that parser, you will have lots of fun!

Comment: No, I'm just asking if there is one. Anyway, found an alternative with regex and re.S (DOTALL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a Python parser for grub.cfg, but you don't need to parse the whole file for that information. This is the format for the data you're looking for:

```
menuentry "<name>" [options] {
  ...
  set root='<root>'
  ...
}
```

So look for lines starting with `menuentry`, parse the name from that line, and scan until the next line with a `}` for `set root=`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try parsers [augeas](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas) [libconfuse](https://github.com/libconfuse/libconfuse)  [Devicetree](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/utils/dtc/)

Comment: can you add some examples in your answer? thanks!